# Django Template not loading variables from views

Tags: python, html, django

I created a template in Django, and initialized a very simple HTML code just to test it out with some variables loaded from the views.py file. The HTML file is loaded, but the variables are not. The weird thing is that when I inspect the elements I see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBw9b.png)

Here are my codes:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Structure

def index(request):
    all_structures = Structure.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('Structures/index.html')
    context = {
        'all_structures': all_structures,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, structure_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Structure id " + str(structure_id) + "</h2>")
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      {% for structure in all_structures %}
      <li><a href="/structures/{{ structures.id }}/">{{ structures.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is called `structure`, remove the `s`

```
<li><a href="/structures/{{ structure.id }}/">{{ structure.name }}</a></li>
```

About the `SA password protected entry checker` I found this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/936955/strange-sa-checker-attributes-being-added-to-body-tag), it doesn't seems to be django but the antivirus or some browser extension.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your function like this :

```
def index(request):
    all_structures = Structure.objects.all()
    context = {
        'all_structures': all_structures,
    }
    return render(request, 'Structures/index.html', context)
```

Then :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      {% for structure in all_structures %}
      <li><a href="/structures/{{ structure.id }}/">{{ structure.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

You have to write `{structure.field}` and not `{structures.field}`

Comment: The problem was indeed the added S in structures. Your render function does not work. I left it as is as I'm watching a tutorial by thenewboston channel. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you import this : `from django.shortcuts import render` ^^

Comment: Hahaha, no I did not. That's why it said render not defined. Sorry man it's lunch time and I'm not concentrated at all :o

Comment: You're welcome ;)
If my answer or @Julio's answer is better for you, don' forget to validate

Comment: I did. But since I'm new, my feedback is only shared with the moderators, not publically :)